# How to make Chrome redraw SVG dynamically added content?

Tags: javascript, svg

I've dynamacally added the circle elements to the svg displayed in a iFrame. Chrome isnt showing the new elements, not tried FF yet. Is there somekind of redraw/refresh I need to call? The first circle is actually in the svg document, the rest come from script.

```
<iframe id="svgFrame" src="xmlfile1.svg" width="300" height="300">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="SVG1" width="200" height="200">
   <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="5"/>
   <circle cx="165" cy="80" r="32"/>
   <circle cx="15" cy="38" r="32"/>
   <circle cx="140" cy="39" r="30"/>
   <circle cx="178" cy="32" r="22"/>
   ...etc
   <circle cx="166" cy="130" r="16"/>
</svg>
</iframe>
```

The javascript which creates the elements:

```
function RandomNumber(min, max) {
    var r;
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return r;
}

var svg = document.getElementById("svgFrame").contentDocument;

for (var i = 0; i < 99; i++) {

    var n = svg.createElement("circle");
    n.setAttribute("cx" , RandomNumber( 0 , 200) );
    n.setAttribute("cy" , RandomNumber(0, 200) );
    n.setAttribute("r"  , RandomNumber(5, 35) );

    svg.documentElement.appendChild(n);
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I haven't tried what you are doing where you essentially have two sources but I do know Chrome doesn't need a refresh/redraw when dynamically adding content.

Here is my code maybe this will help you.

```
xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var C = document.createElementNS(xmlns,"circle");
C.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", cx);
C.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", cy);
C.setAttributeNS(null, "r", rad);
document.getElementById("background").appendChild(C);
```

Where background is just the id of a group (g tag)

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: Why do you use ".contentDocument" ?

Comment: only used .contentDocument because is was the first prop i found that had a createElement method - have since seen there is a getSVGDocument method... is that the more correct one to use?

Comment: Using the NS version seem to have fixed it - again i'm puzzled, i assumed that they were children of SVG they would have the same namespaces....

Comment: Did you have to change createElementNS and setAttributeNS or just the first?

Comment: Just the createElementNS - i tested both - both worked, but setAttibuteNS(null, ...,...) MUST be equivalent to setAttribute(..,...)!

Comment: contentDocument means essentially the same thing as getSVGDocument, if you're developing new content I'd suggest using contentDocument since getSVGDocument will become deprecated with the next revision of SVG 1.1, see http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/publish/struct.html#InterfaceGetSVGDocument

Comment: Helped me so much! Backbone View's tagName(){return 'circle' } under the hood also tries to create HTML element, so I also needed this trick

Comment: Note that the xmlns is necessary, but the setAttributeNS(null,...) is not. You can use setAttribute(key, value) instead.

Answer (score 18):

I'm guessing, but have you tried `createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","circle")` instead of `createElement("circle")`?

Comment: I'll try it, but querying the document with Inspect Element, seem to show the correct namespace. After all createElement is called from an object with the correct namespace...

Comment: Have just tried it and it know works - must have read the inspector wrong when i comes to the namespaces.....

Comment: Also after just looking at the DOM in the Inpector, i'd have thought that adding the elements as children of svg they would have the same namespace as svg...

Comment: From a quick read of DOM2 Core, it doesn't look like that to me, but I'm not 100% sure. Worth a try, I would have thought.

Comment: I'm not convinced the Chrome DOM inspector is exactly correct, especially w.r.t. namespaces.  I don't have any example offhand, but I seem to recall having issue with that before.

Comment: @Matthew both yours and Shaun's answer came in a nearly this same time - he 'needs' the points more than you! ( your turn next )