# Including SVG template in Angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, svg, angularjs

```
<div ng-app="testrectApp">
<svg>
    <rect height="10" width="10" style="fill: #00ff00" />
    <testrect />
</svg>
</div>
```

And this is my directive

```
module.directive('testrect', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<rect top="20" left="20" height="10" width="10" style="fill: #ff00ff" />',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

But this is what the element ends up looking like in the browser. The fill twice is not a typo.

```
<rect top="20" left="20" height="10" width="10" style="fill: #ff00ff;fill: #ff00ff"></rect>
```

Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RG2CF/

Is what I'm trying to do not possible or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: I should add that the issue may have to do with the fact that the template svg rect is namespaced to xhtml instead of svg, but I'm unsure of how I can force this or namespace it back to svg, if that is actually the solution.

Comment: Similar discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/nP5JSuRuBMw/Wkv4DGMrtEUJ (seems to me like the way AngularJS deals with templates doesn't support SVG)

Comment: Thanks for that. It's very helpful. I'm getting the impression that the Google group is where most of the Angularjs discussion goes on.

Comment: the "fill twice" does not appears when the angular version is changed. It seems specific to 1.2.1. Maybe introduced by : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e1254b266dfa2d4e3756e4317152dbdbcabe44be#diff-a732922b631efed1b9f33a24082ae0dbR1595

Answer (score 29):

There is a `templateNamespace` property you can set to `svg`:

```
module.directive('testrect', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateNamespace: 'svg',
        template: '<rect .../>',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

Here is a [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to the documentation.

Comment: This is the correct answer now. I'll update my answer to point at yours

Answer (score 19):

**Angular 1.3 Update!**

My original answer below was a giant hack at best. What you should really do is update to Angular 1.3 and set the `templateNamespace:'svg'` property on your directive. Look below at @Josef Pfleger answer for an example: [Including SVG template in Angularjs directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641105/including-svg-template-in-angularjs-directive/27675374#27675374)

---

**Old Answer**

In case anyone comes across this in the future, I was able to create a compile function that works with svg templates. Its a bit ugly right now, so refactoring help is much appreciated.

live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/DN2M3M?p=preview

```
app.service('svgService', function(){

    var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var compileNode = function(angularElement){
      var rawElement = angularElement[0];

      //new lines have no localName
      if(!rawElement.localName){
        var text = document.createTextNode(rawElement.wholeText);
        return angular.element(text);
      }
      var replacement = document.createElementNS(xmlns,rawElement.localName);
      var children = angularElement.children();

      angular.forEach(children, function (value) {
        var newChildNode = compileNode(angular.element(value));
        replacement.appendChild(newChildNode[0]);
      });

      if(rawElement.localName === 'text'){
        replacement.textContent = rawElement.innerText;
      }

      var attributes = rawElement.attributes;
      for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length ; i++) {
        replacement.setAttribute(attributes[i].name, attributes[i].value);
      }

      angularElement.replaceWith(replacement);

      return angular.element(replacement);
    };

    this.compile = function(elem, attrs, transclude) {
      compileNode(elem);

      return function postLink(scope, elem,attrs,controller){
//        console.log('link called');
      };
    }
  })
```

use case:

```
app.directive('ngRectAndText', function(svgService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 
    '<g>'
    + '<rect x="140" y="150" width="25" height="25" fill="red"></rect>'
    + '<text x="140" y="150">Hi There</text>'
    + '</g>'
    ,
    replace: true,
    compile: svgService.compile
  };
});
```

Comment: Dude, after 3 or 4 hours of googleing on how to create svg elements, your service was the first code that worked for me. Thanks mate, you're a live saver!

Comment: Does it work with new angular 1.3.x ? Its supposed to be supported now

Comment: This is great, but I found it does not work for patterns within the defs section. They get inserted and renderend, but the rendering looks VERY different from the original

Comment: One more: If I copy and paste the generated svg and insert the whole thing into some div again it looks as expected, even in IEs.

Comment: Thanks for this piece of code! I've found one issue so far, for `<text>` elements, you are not inserting the text in `replacement`. I'll try to modify the code, but I don't know much about the DOM.

Comment: Now there is a `templateNamespace` property you can set to `svg` (see my answer).

Answer (score 4):

Currently SVG tags don't support dynamic addition of tags, at least in Chrome. It doesn't even display the new rect, nor would it even if you just added it directly with the DOM or JQuery.append(). [Have a look at just trying to do it with JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/7AztC/)

```
// this doesn't even work right. Slightly different error than yours.
$(function() {
    $('svg').append('<rect top="20" left="20" height="10" width="10" style="fill: #ff00ff" />');
});
```

My guess is you're going to see some really crazy behavior no matter what you do in this manner. It seems like it's an issue with the browser, and not so much Angular. [I'd recommend reporting it to the Chromium project](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines).

EDIT:

It looks like it might work if you add it via the DOM 100% programmatically: [How to make Chrome redraw SVG dynamically added content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544686/how-to-make-chrome-redraw-svg-dynamically-added-content)

Comment: I had issues with Firefox as well. Did you actually find this worked in your version of Firefox?

Comment: Yeah, I also had issues with the in FF.

Comment: If you want this to work in the future, contact http://www.whatwg.org/ and/or http://www.w3.org/html/wg/. Because according to the current specs the above rect will just become an HTMLUnknownElement in the DOM.

Answer (score 4):

Using an innerHTML shim for SVG (aka "innerSVG") provides another piece of this puzzle, as an alternative to Jason More's insightful answer. I feel this innerHTML/innerSVG approach is more elegant because it does not require a special compile function like Jason's answer, but it has at least one drawback: it does not work if "replace: true" is set on the directive. (The innerSVG approach is discussed here: [Is there some innerHTML replacement in SVG/XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723422/is-there-some-innerhtml-replacement-in-svg-xml))

```
// Inspiration for this derived from a shim known as "innerSVG" which adds
// an "innerHTML" attribute to SVGElement:
Object.defineProperty(SVGElement.prototype, 'innerHTML', {
  get: function() {
    // TBD!
  },
  set: function(markup) {
    // 1. Remove all children
    while (this.firstChild) {
      this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
    }

    // 2. Parse the SVG
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
        '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">'
        + markup
        + '</svg>',
        'application/xml'
    );

    // 3. Import the parsed SVG and grab the childNodes
    var contents = this.ownerDocument.importNode(doc.documentElement, true).childNodes;

    // 4. Append the childNodes to this node
    // Note: the following for loop won't work because as items are appended,
    // they are removed from contents (you'd end up with only every other
    // element getting appended and the other half remaining still in the
    // original document tree):
    //for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    //  this.appendChild(contents[i]);
    //}
    while (contents.length) {
      this.appendChild(contents[0]);
    }
  },
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true
});
```

Here's a Plunker to try: http://plnkr.co/edit/nEqfbbvpUCOVC1XbTKdQ?p=preview

The reason why this works is: SVG elements live within the XML namespace, http://www.w3.org/2000/svg, and as such, they must either be parsed with DOMParser() or instantiated with createElementNS() (as in Jason's answer), both of which can set the namespace appropriately. It would be nice if this process of using SVG was as easy as HTML, but unfortunately their DOM structures are subtly different which results in the need to supply our own innerHTML shim. Now, if we could also get "replace: true" to work with this, that will be something good!

EDIT: Updated the appendChild() loop to workaround contents changing while loop runs.

Answer (score 0):

angular doesn't pay attentention to namespaces when creating elements (though elements seem to be cloned with namepsace of a parent), so new directives inside `<svg>` won't work without a custom compile function.

Something like the following can get around the issue by doing the creation of the dom elements itself.  For this to work, you need to have `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` as an attribute on the root element of `template` and your template must be valid XML (having only one root element).

```
directiveGenerator = function($compile) {
  var ret, template;
  template = "<g xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"> +
             "<rect top=\"20\" left=\"20\" height=\"10\" width=\"10\" style=\"fill: #ff00ff\" />" +
             "</g>";
  ret = {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function(elm, attrs, transclude) {
      var templateElms;
      templateElms = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(template, 'application/xml');
      elm.replaceWith(templateElms.documentElement);
      return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        // Your link function
      };
    }
  };
  return ret;
};

angular.module('svg.testrect', []).directive('testrec', directiveGenerator);
```