# AngularJS creating HTMLElements instead of SVGElements

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

I have two directives, `my-svg` and `my-rect`. I want to use them like this:

```
    <svg my-svg>
      <my-rect/>
    </svg>
```

`my-rect` creates an SVG `rect` and `my-svg` creates an `svg` node with the transcluded rectangle inside. In the end, what I want to get is:

```
    <svg width='300' height='300'>
      <rect x="140" y="30" width="25" height="25" fill="red"></rect>
    </svg>
```

See example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/UIyUtX?p=preview

As you can see, the red rectangle isn't displayed, even though it exists in the DOM. According to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641105/including-svg-template-in-angularjs-directive), it seems that the rectangle isn't displayed because it is an HTMLElement when it should be an SVGElement.

As suggested in that same discussion, I'm using a custom directive compiler to transform the DOM nodes from type HTMLElement to SVGElement, but even that doesn't seem to work in my use-case.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hoods AngularJS uses JQuery or JQLite to create elements from templates to replace with.

JQuery and JQLite both use document.createElement rather than document.createElementNS with the correct SVG namespace.

<s>In your directive you need to take over the creation of SVG elements from AngularJS.</s>

You can inject the following helper function into your directive:

```
.value('createSVGNode', function(name, element, settings) {
  var namespace = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
  var node = document.createElementNS(namespace, name);
  for (var attribute in settings) {
    var value = settings[attribute];
    if (value !== null && !attribute.match(/\$/) && (typeof value !== 'string' || value !== '')) {
      node.setAttribute(attribute, value);
    }
  }
  return node;
})
```

And make use of it in the link function rather than using a template (either external or inline) - something like:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  var cx = '{{x}';
  var cy = '{{y}}';
  var r = '{{r}}';
  var circle = createSVGNode('circle', element, attrs);

  angular.element(circle).attr('ng-attr-cx', cx);
  angular.element(circle).attr('ng-attr-cy', cy);
  angular.element(circle).attr('ng-attr-r', r);
  element.replaceWith(circle);

  $compile(circle)(scope);
}
```

You can see an example of this working - in a piechart context - over at https://github.com/mjgodfrey83/angular-piechart/.

A fix landed in angular 1.3.0-beta8 to allow non html directive template types to be specified - see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f0e12ea7fea853192e4eead00b40d6041c5f914a). For an example of it being used check out [angular-charts](https://github.com/crudbetter/angular-charts/).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Putting

```
<g>
    <my-rect></my-rect>
</g>
```

will display the rectangle. 
It doesn't answer the question what are you doing wrong, but it does get the code to display what you want. I spent some time looking at this problem myself but I could not get it to work , and so solved the problem in a different way. What is the problem you are trying to solve using this method?