# When I use AngularJS directive in svg the result is not presented

Tags: angularjs, svg

I'm trying to create AngularJS directive that I will use inside svg element.
The directive do not create svg element but use exist one.
I can see the right svg markup in the dev-tools but the browser does not display it.

[Please see live example](http://jsfiddle.net/6Sc8L/1/).

This is the directive:

```
angular.module('ui.directives', []).directive('svgText', 
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          template: '<text fill="green" x="4" y="20" font-weight="bolder" font-size="2" font-family="Arial">89</text>'
      };
    }
  );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including SVG template in Angularjs directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641105/including-svg-template-in-angularjs-directive)

Answer (score 8):

This happens because jQuery (which AngularJS uses under the hood) doesn't know how to create svg elements. You can workaround this by adding a *link* function to the directive that clones the element that was created but creates it in the SVG namespace.

A potentially better method is to wrap your template in an SVG element (with namespace defined) and then in the *link* function pull out the child element and use that, it will already be created in the correct namespace.

```
module.directive(
    'svgText',
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><text fill="green" x="4" y="20" font-weight="bolder" font-size="2" font-family="Arial">89</text></svg>',
            replace: true,

            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                // Extract the child element to replace the SVG element.
                var child = angular.element(elem[0].firstElementChild);

                // Copy attributes into element.
                for (attrName in attrs) {
                    if(typeof attrs[attrName] === "string") {
                        child.attr(attrName, attrs[attrName]);
                    }
                }
                elem.replaceWith(child );
            }
        };
    }
);
```

I have published an article on AngularJS + SVG which talks through many such issues.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/709340/Implementing-a-Flowchart-with-SVG-and-AngularJS

Comment: Thanks so much for this, for the life of me I couldn't understand the problem. This should actually be mentioned in the AngularJS documentation.

Comment: Note: This also works with a `templateUrl:` that references a regular svg file. The svg file can contain angular directives too, even ng-transclude. Great work!