# Angular: How to include static html into dom without surrounding element?

Tags: angularjs, templates, svg, parent

in Angular I want to include a static html template containing svg 'pattern' elements into an inline svg. Is there a way to include just the html without any surrounding tag, div, whatever in Angular?

I've tried ng-include and a directive.

Html Code I want:

```
    <svg 
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
    >
      <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
           ...
        </style>

        <pattern id="someid"
         ...
        </pattern>

        <pattern id="someotherid"
         ...
        </pattern>

        ... !!!much more patterns!!!...
     </defs>
     ...content...
   </svg>
```

Html Code I get:

```
<directive> <pattern>... </directive>
```

The problem is, that any sourrounding element will break rendering of the svg. The spec does not allow this.

**EDIT:**

it seems that you have to create any element you want to append to an svg in a proper svg-namespace.

a angular service with custom compile doing that can be found here: [Including SVG template in Angularjs directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641105/including-svg-template-in-angularjs-directive)

This works for elements in svg body, but not for patterns.. :-(

They get inserted fine, but the rendering breaks and looks weird

Comment: could you add a jsfiddle or plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup! You can just use the `replace` attribute for your directive definition, which replaces the original element in the DOM.

Example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jmJi5Q5mp5DDc3xOhJQ8?p=preview

Comment: I thought replace was deprecated as of 2.0?

Comment: True, replace is deprecated and it's there exacly for my purpose:

"replace ([DEPRECATED!], will be removed in next major release - i.e. v2.0)

...
There are very few scenarios where element replacement is required for the application function, the main one being reusable custom components that are used within SVG contexts (because SVG doesn't work with custom elements in the DOM tree)."

Sadly svg-rendering does not work within the defs section if the svg.. 

It needs to be a single 'pattern' element, that truly ends up rendered in the svg-dom, but the svg itself does not update..

Comment: You can always modify the parent element itself in the `link` function, if this functionality gets removed. Something like `element.html(<your compiled SVG node>)` might work too