# How to get the svg element's changing width/height in an angular Directive?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I have a directive as below, where I defined a d3 svg attribute's width of 100%. I need to get the value of back in px. I was able to access the SVGLength object using console.log((svg[0])[0].width.baseVal).

But whenever the value changes, the object is getting updated but, when I print console.log((svg[0])[0].width.baseVal.value) - I always get 0.

Is there a way, i can add a watch on the element's baseVal?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

angular.module('sortron.directives').directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {data: "="},
    replace: true,
    template: '<svg id="chart"></svg>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var checkForNewVal = function (newVal, oldVal) {
        var svg = d3.select("#chart");
        svg.selectAll('*').remove();
        var bar =  svg.attr("width", "100%")
                      .attr("height", "100%")
                      .selectAll("svg")
                      .data(newVal)
                      .enter();
        console.log((svg[0])[0].width.baseVal);
      };
      // Add watch on the data
      scope.$watch('data', checkForNewVal,true);
    }
  }
});
```

Also, I see

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641105/including-svg-template-in-angularjs-directive and templateNamespace:  'svg' https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile