# SVG <g> element size is set to zero despite it has children

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, svg

I add some elements to svg containing one big group. Basic code of the group looks like this:

```
<svg ng-attr-view-box="{{getViewbox()}}"
     width="100%" height="100%">

    <!-- This will be global group element I refer below -->
    <g ng-transclude></g>    
</svg>
```

When just after page is loaded it requests list of elements (actually several lists) to display and then elements are added to the page. Each element looks something like:

```
<g class="element-view">
    <circle ng-attr-cx="{{model.x}}"
            ng-attr-cy="{{model.y}}"
            style="fill:blue"
            r="4">
    </circle>
    <path ng-attr-d="....">
    </path>
</g>
```

In Chrome on some loads upper group has zero size despite all elements are correctly loaded and added to DOM. And nothing is displayed. Second list of elements is not displayed at all but all the elements are at the place and all <g> elements of second list also have 0 size despite child svg tags are properly set up with coordinates and sizes.

I Firefox global group size is always zero.

Does anyone knows why browsers do not set proper size of <g> element?

P.S. I have a guess that reason for this could be that parent element or svg view-box is set to zero and then to some value during setting up page layout and for some reason <g> is not resized after this. But I have no idea how to debug it.

Comment: This generally happens because you're creating the elements in the wrong namespace.

Comment: Can you please tell me which ns is correct? How should it be done correctly?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/2000/svg I don't know you haven't posted the code you're using to create the elements.

Comment: No, adding this to svg tag does not help. Actually resulting svg is <svg><g> [ Many element view elements ] </g></svg> Code which creates HTML just gets array of data from service, pushes it ti $scope variable and then angular does it's job by looping over array and creating child <g>... for each element-view.

Comment: <svg ng-attr-view-box="{{getViewbox()}}"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"
     version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="100%" height="100%">

    <g ng-transclude></g>
</svg>

Comment: No changes for child items

Comment: How are you adding that? ng-attr-view-box is not something a browser understands so there must be some angular wrapping code which you're not showing us.

Comment: This is it: scope.getViewbox = function () { return ctrl.viewBox.x + ' ' + ctrl.viewBox.y + ' ' + ctrl.viewBox.w + ' ' + ctrl.viewBox.h; };

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131718/discussion-between-dmytro-and-robert-longson).

Comment: Indeed, this solution works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that to use svg elements in the angular template proper template namespace should be specified for every template. This should be done using templateNamespace directive parameter for example like this:

```
.directive('cuiPluginview', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/components/views/module/view.html',
        templateNamespace: 'svg',
        replace: true,
```

See this question for more info: [Including SVG template in Angularjs directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641105/including-svg-template-in-angularjs-directive)