# SVG element in html not showing

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to show a SVG graphic inside my html page; in the page, in a div, I have this code:

```
<svg id="Scanvas" width="800" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs><style type="text/css">
        polygon{
            stroke: #168fdc;
            stroke-width: 5;
            fill: #95CFF4;
            opacity: 0.75;
            /*fill-rule: nonzero;*/
        }       
    </style></defs>
    <g transform="translate(152.45,250) scale(225,-225)">
        <polygon points="-0.5,1 0.5,1 0.5,-1 -0.5,-1"></polygon>
    </g>
</svg>
```

But the page shows nothing. More precisely, in the page style I set a background for the svg tag and it shows, but no elements are displayed inside it.

How can I make things show correctly?
Thanks

**EDIT:** Working on google chrome

**EDIT2:** Tried the same svg in jsfiddle.net, and there it works. Looking into the source code, it seems they put the style inside the head tag in the html, however this doesn't work in my page

**EDIT3:** Putting a polygon outside the  make both polygons show:

```
<svg id="Scanvas" width="800" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <polygon points="0,0 10,0 10,10 0,10"></polygon>
    <g transform="translate(152.5,250) scale(225,-225)">
        <polygon points="-0.5,1 0.5,1 0.5,-1 -0.5,-1 "></polygon>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Can someone explain me that?

**LAST EDIT** At the end I found the issue: I didn't mentioned I was creating the svg polygons with javascript, and due to a namespace issue (this is what I understood) tags were created but not displayed. Found the answer here: [How to make Chrome redraw SVG dynamically added content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544686/how-to-make-chrome-redraw-svg-dynamically-added-content).

Comment: Which browser(s) have you tried so far?

Comment: working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/jPm97/

Answer (score 1):

Your polygon is **overscaled** if that makes a sense. So You see a rendering of the polygon over entire rendering area.

Try to load this modified code into SVG enabled browser:

```
<svg id="Scanvas" width="800" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs><style type="text/css">
        polygon{
            stroke: #168fdc;
            stroke-width: 5;
            fill: #95CFF4;
            opacity: 0.75;
            /*fill-rule: nonzero;*/
        }       
    </style></defs>
    <g transform="translate(152.45,250)">
        <polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100"></polygon>
    </g>
</svg>
```

and then try this one:

```
<svg id="Scanvas" width="800" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs><style type="text/css">
        polygon{
            stroke: #168fdc;
            stroke-width: 5;
            fill: #95CFF4;
            opacity: 0.75;
            /*fill-rule: nonzero;*/
        }       
    </style></defs>
    <g transform="translate(152.45,250) scale(2,2)">
        <polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100"></polygon>
    </g>
</svg>
```

This will give You an idea of how much to scale.
Supose You already have read a [polygon](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/shapes.html#PolygonElement).

EDIT
Code was tested in an independent file, containing only the SVG code snippet. Tested under Chromium. Definitely shows difference from Your sample code (as given). Under plain Ubuntu (if that makes any diff).

Comment: The scale parameters are calculated by a javascript function to fit the canvas size, keeping a padding around; I also manually tried your codes but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Because your scale is humongus, and the stroke-width is set at 5, which is greater than the size of the polygon itself, the only thing that displays is the stroke. Try setting your stroke-width=.1

Comment: Sorry I can't understand the meaning of "humongus" :D
I tried to set stroke-width:1, nothing changed