# g-tag does not work when used in replace directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my code:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

// this directive replaces itself with a <g> tag
app.directive('hexagonReplace', function(){
    return {
      templateUrl: 'hexagonReplace.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope:{
          dx: '=',
          dy: '='
      }
    };
});

// this directive appends a <g> tag with a polygon forming a hexagon
app.directive('hexagonAppend', function(){
    return {
      templateUrl: 'hexagonAppend.html',
      restrict: 'A'
    };
});
```

hexagonReplace.html

```
<g class='hexagon' ng-attr-transform='translate({{dx}},{{dy}})'>
  <polygon points="21.65063509461097,-12.499999999999998 21.65063509461097,12.499999999999998 1.5308084989341915e-15,25 -21.65063509461097,12.499999999999998 -21.65063509461097,-12.499999999999993 -4.592425496802574e-15,-25">
  </polygon>
</g>
```

hexagonAppend.html

```
<polygon points="21.65063509461097,-12.499999999999998 21.65063509461097,12.499999999999998 1.5308084989341915e-15,25 -21.65063509461097,12.499999999999998 -21.65063509461097,-12.499999999999993 -4.592425496802574e-15,-25">
</polygon>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <svg width=100 height=100>
      <!-- This hexagon will not be shown -->
      <hexagon-replace dx=50 dy=50></hexagon-replace>
      <rect class='outline' width=100 height=100></rect>
    </svg>
    <svg width=100 height=100>
      <!-- This hexagon looks almost the same in the resulting html but is displayed properly -->
      <g class='hexagon' transform='translate(50,50)' hexagon-append></g>
      <rect class='outline' width=100 height=100></rect>
    </svg>
  </body>

</html>
```

style.css

```
/* Put your css in here */

.hexagon {
  stroke: black;
  fill: pink;
}

.outline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

Try it out at http://plnkr.co/edit/lzET3CMrth2uHTSfCity

I'd like to create an svg element with several hexagons. In order to clean up the code and to reduce redundancy, I'd like to have some 'hexagon' element that I can put into the svg-node.
Unfortunately it does not work as expected.

When the hexagon-node is replaced with my template, then the polygon-subnode seems to be inactive for some reason.

If I use the 'hexagon' directive to add a polygon-node to an existing g-node it works fine. This is however not my preferred solution since in this case I will have redundant attributes for each g-node.

Any Ideas?

Edit: I noticed that actually in Firefox both do not show up. Whereas in chromium the behavior is as described.

2nd Edit:
Those two seem related... actually the first one already answers my question.
I will look for a different approach then.
[Including SVG template in Angularjs directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641105/including-svg-template-in-angularjs-directive)
[How to make Chrome redraw SVG dynamically added content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544686/how-to-make-chrome-redraw-svg-dynamically-added-content)